# Dictionaries, autorelease pools, and temporary objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

Let's say I have a dictionary full of objects for keys that may or may not be there. What is the standard practice for checking whether this key exists or not?

For example, what I've written looks like this:

```
    id temp;

    temp = [dict objectForKey: @"id"];
    if (temp != [NSNull null]) {
        uid = [temp intValue];
    }

    temp = [dict objectForKey: @"name"];
    if (temp) {
        [name release];
        name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: temp];
    }

    temp = [dict objectForKey: @"latitude"];
    if (temp != [NSNull null]) {
        [latitude release];
        latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: [temp doubleValue]];
    }

    temp = [dict objectForKey: @"longitude"];
    if (temp != [NSNull null]) {
        [longitude release];
        longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: [temp doubleValue]];
    }
```

Should I surround this code with an autorelease pool? Do I have to release each time I point temp to an object in the dictionary, or does the pool handle that automatically? Is there a better way to handle errors?

Comment: I believe that if the object is not in the dictionary, then nil will be returned, rather than NSNull object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the method described in this post: [How to map JSON objects to Objective C classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739067/how-to-map-json-objects-to-objective-c-classes/5757530#5757530)

Answer (score 1):

[`objectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHCDIDJ) does **not** return an autoreleased object, it returns a direct pointer to the desired object, therefore you do **not** need an inner autorelease pool here.

If the desired object is not found, [`objectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHCDIDJ) will return `nil`, so that is what you should be testing here:

```
id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"someKey"];
if(obj == nil) {
   //not found
}
```

Also, it looks like you might want to declare those instance variables as retained properties if you're going to be doing this all over the place:

```
[ivar release];
ivar = ...;
```

Declare the properties in your `.h` file like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
```

Then you'd do this within your `@implementation`:

```
@synthesize latitude;
```

Once that's done, you can simply do the following instead:

```
self.latitude = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty informative. But what do you mean by the last part, "declare those instance variables as retained properties"? Basically I had allocated and initialized the variables earlier before I entered this section of the code, so that in case it wasn't found, I would still have an empty NSString or whatnot for when other classes were trying to access this one.